# Toast Animation in Blackberry 7.0 api

Tags: blackberry, java-me

I want to be able to fire a toast animation which appears when I enter a screen by pushing the other fields down. The field should appear as a blank field, then animate the toast with the text and reduce back to the blank field. What are the api's in blackberry 7.0 backward that I can look at?

Comment: will you explain little more ?

Comment: I am trying to make a text field show up gradually/ expand into view

Answer (score 0):

My first thought would be to extend a PopUpField, adding a Labelfield to it. Then upon pushing it start a thread that repaints the label text with ascending and descending alpha values.

This was off the top of my head, there might be a better solution